# Taylor expansion at two different points.

Tags: taylor-expansion

My question is stated in the image. 
I want to prove that every coefficient is same for all terms. But it is not easy. 
Can you give me some direct proof? [image]

Comment: Have you tried using any theorems relating to the convergence of Taylor series in proving this result?

Answer (score 0):

You're not suppose to prove that every coefficient is the same. Instead, you need to show that the functions defined by the Taylor polynomials are the same.

Comment: I know two functions are the same. But I want to prove it in another way.